# Moving wordpress to Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm planning to move my Website which is using multiple wordpress to Amazon Services. However, my daily vistors are about 22,000 and sometimes goes to over 90k and the web crashes! However, the hosting company charge me nearly $100 including support without support it would cost $50. the average bandwidth is about 400GB.

Can I ask please how much will it cost me? and how I can start with Amazon Services?

Kind regards

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/setting-up-wordpress-on-amazon-ec2/ This might help you, it's a tutorial on how to setup wordpress on AWS via Bitnami

Answer (score 4):

Start out by looking at the different types of hosting that [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/) offers and which one will be the correct fit for your site.  [Amazon's EC2 (Elastic Cloud Computing)](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) is the servers that you can get hosted in the cloud.

Depending on how much storage space and bandwidth, the costs differ.  They have a helpful cost guide on [their EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing) page.  They offer different pricing for the different types of servers you need.  They have on demand [spot instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/) which can be brought up and down on the fly.  If you need a server to be running constantly you can put a down payment and have a [reserved instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/) to provide the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate your fees depending on your current usage from the tools AWS provides. http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

This is also a good article for getting started with using WordPress under AWS. 
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scaling-caching/deploy-your-wordpress-blog-to-the-cloud/

AWS also provides a Free Tier of services provided you stay under a certain amount of usage. That is detailed at http://aws.amazon.com/free/ . I also found this YouTube video on setting up EC2 instances very helpful. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPFoDnjR8e8 . From what I understand, unless your WordPress install gets a crazy number of hits you will probably fall under the Free Tier.

Comment: Thanks!! The point is that I don't know how to use the tools AWS provides :( so that's why I came here. I don't know what should I put

Comment: The thing that was confusing to me was that AWS is actually a virtual machine which you then install a web service and eventually a website or WordPress into. It's different from traditional hosting in a lot of ways because you are basically being given a blank machine to configure how you want. Is your question more about the tools or more about how to get up and running with AWS? The second link should get you going with a step-by-step including the base AWS tools. I will expand my answer with another option.

Comment: It should be pointed out EC2 is only free for 12 months for the free tier.